# $routeParams is empty in main controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this piece of layout html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div id="terminal"></div>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <!-- including scripts -->
</body>
```

Now apparently, when I try to use `$routeParams` in `MainController`, it's always empty.  It's important to note that `MainController` is supposed to be in effect in every possible route; therefore I'm not defining it in my app.js.  I mean, I'm not defining it here:

```
$routeProvider.when("/view1", {
  templateUrl: "partials/partial1.html"
  controller: "MyCtrl1"
})

$routeProvider.when("/view2", {
  templateUrl: "partials/partial2.html"
  controller: "MyCtrl2"
})

// I'm not defining MainController here!!
```

In fact, I think my problem is perfectly the same as this one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ib2wHQozeNE

However, I still don't get how to get route parameters in my main controller...

EDIT:

What I meant was that I'm not associating my MainController with any specific route.  It's defined; and it's the parent controller of all other controllers.  What I'm trying to know is that when you go to a URL like `/whatever`, which is matched by a route like `/:whatever`, why is it that only the sub-controller is able to access the route parameter, whereas the main controller is not?  How do I get the `:whatever` route parameter in my main controller?

Comment: Ok, then where do you define it? If the module doesn't know about, then...?

Answer (score 72):

The `$routeParams` service is populated asynchronously. This means it will typically appear empty when first used in a controller.

To be notified when `$routeParams` has been populated, subscribe to the `$routeChangeSuccess` event on the `$scope`. (If you're in a component that doesn't have access to a child `$scope`, e.g., a service or a factory, you can inject and use `$rootScope` instead.)

```js
module.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams should be populated here
  });
);
```

Controllers used by a route, or within a template included by a route, will have immediate access to the fully-populated `$routeParams` because `ng-view` waits for the `$routeChangeSuccess` event before continuing. (It *has* to wait, since it needs the route information in order to decide which template/controller to even load.)

If you know your controller will be used inside of `ng-view`, you won't need to wait for the routing event. If you know your controller will not, you will. If you're not sure, you'll have to explicitly allow for both possibilities. Subscribing to `$routeChangeSuccess` will not be enough; you will only see the event if `$routeParams` wasn't already populated:

```js
module.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  // $routeParams will already be populated
  // here if this controller is used within ng-view

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams will be populated here if
    // this controller is used outside ng-view
  });
);
```

Comment: Great! Very well-written.

Comment: I am using stateprovider.. so its never called.. but when i use `$stateChangeSuccess` then `r$outeParams ` still empty object

Comment: @Sami: you need to use $stateParams instead of $routeParams

Answer (score 4):

As an alternate to the $timeout that plong0 mentioned...

You can also inject the $route service which will show your params immediately.

```
angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $route) {
      console.log('routeParams:'+JSON.stringify($route.current.params));
  });
```

Comment: for me the `$routeChangeSuccess` was not firing sometimes and `$route.current.params` saved me! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

What I discovered is that, $routeParams take some time to load in the Main Controller, it probably initiate the Main Controller first and then set $routeParams at the Child Controller. I did a workaround for it creating a method in the Main Controller $scope and pass $routeParams through it in the Child Controllers:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MainController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod = function($routeParams) {
     //do stuff
    }
  }]);

angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MyCtrl1', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod($routeParams);
  }]);

angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MyCtrl2', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod($routeParams);
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, and building off what Andre mentioned in his answer about $routeParams taking a moment to load in the main controller, I just put it in a timeout inside my MainCtrl.

```
angular.module('MyModule')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function(){
      // do stuff with $routeParams
      console.log('routeParams:'+JSON.stringify($routeParams));
    }, 20);

  });
```

20ms delay to use $routeParams is not even noticeable, and less than that seems to have inconsistent results.

More specifically about my problem, I was confused because I had the exact same setup working with a different project structure (yo cg-angular) and when I rebuilt my project (yo angular-fullstack) I started experiencing the problem.

Comment: filed issue on angularjs github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7053

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems here:

- with `$routeParams` you get the route parameters, which you didn't define
- the file where you define a main controller doesn't really matter. the important thing is in which module/function

The parameters have to be defined with the `$routeProvider` with the syntax `:paramName`:

```
$routeProvider.when("/view2/name1/:a/name2/:b"
```

and then you can retrieve them with `$routeParams.paramName`.

You can also use the query parameters, like `index.html?k1=v1&k2=v2`.

`app.js` is the file where you'd normally define dependencies and configuration (that's why you'd have  there the app module `.config` block) and it contains the application module:

```
var myapp = angular.module(...);
```

This module can have other modules as dependencies, like directives or services, or a module per feature.
A simple approach is to have a module to encapsulate controllers. An approach closer to your original code is putting at least one controller in the main module:

```
myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {...}
```

Maybe you defined the controller as a global function? `function MainCtrl() {...}`? This pollutes the global namespace. avoid it.

Defining your controller in the main module will not make it "to take effect in all  routes". This has to be defined with  `$routeProvider` or make the controller of each route "inherit" from the main controller. This way, the controller of each route is instantiated *after* the route has changed, whereas the main controller is instantiated only once, when the line `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` is reached (which happens only once, during application startup)

Comment: Hey, could you show some code using the 'inherit' approach ? I'm curious about how could you do that ?

Comment: hi @CHAPa maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-contoller-in-the-same-module I guess you can have a controller in a div higher than `ng-view`

Comment: the controller inheritance means scope inheritance ? if yes, we could create a outer controller that has inside the ng-view. Thanks Eduard

Comment: ah yep, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass values of $routeParams defined into your controller into the $rootScope

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, MainFactory, $rootScope) {
    $scope.contents = MainFactory.getThing($routeParams.id);
    $rootScope.total = MainFactory.getMax(); // Send total to the rootScope
}
```

and inject $rootScope in your IndexCtrl (related to the index.html)

```
.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
    // Some code
});
```