# Can an AngularJS controller inherit from another controller in the same module?

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-controller

Within a module, a controller can inherit properties from an outside controller:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

var ParentCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
};

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {
  $injector.invoke(ParentCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});
});
```

Example via: **Dead link**: <strike>http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2013/02/controller-inheritance-in-angularjs.html</strike>

Can also a controller inside a module inherit from a sibling?

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function($scope) {
  //I'm the sibling, but want to act as parent
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {
  $injector.invoke(ParentCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope}); //This does not work
});
```

The second code does not work since `$injector.invoke` requires a function as first parameter and does not find the reference to `ParentCtrl`.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828287/what-things-can-be-injected-into-others-in-angular-js

Comment: aside: this doesn't look like inheritance, but more like sharing methods or injecting.  Perhaps just semantics.

Comment: The link for the example isn't valid anymore.

Comment: Google Cache Link: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vnn3hY3toEIJ:blog.omkarpatil.com/2013/02/controller-inheritance-in-angularjs.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk
which points to this interesting Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mhevery/u6s88/12/

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Yes, it can but you have to use the `$controller` service to instantiate the controller instead:-

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
  // I'm the sibling, but want to act as parent
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); //This works
});
```

Comment: `ParentCtrl` should be a `controller` or is it possible to use a `service` ?

Comment: @gontard: In this case it must be a controller, as `$controller` can only use registered controllers.

Comment: It is a very good solution. Thank you. But how would I do it in case I am using Controller As syntax?

Comment: @ToKa Same as other controllers? `ChildCtrl as toka`

Comment: @ToKa What are you referring to by "Controller As syntax"? Show me some code.

Comment: How is it done with controller as?..  the jsfiddle above does not include it?

Comment: The above fiddle was asked as a question. It's worth noting that controllerAs simply assigns the controller to the scope - So you would change `$scope` to `this` (in theory)

Comment: @DanPantry Thanks, replacing `$scope` to `this` allows usage of `controller as` syntax

Comment: This worked for me, however I'm trying to do this in a way that I have the parent controller and the child controller on the same page.  This causes the $http operation in the parent controller to run twice.  When the child controller injects the scope of the parent controller my $scope.AllMembers array get's populated twice as the parent controller causes it to run, then the child controller causes it to run again.  Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: For people looking for solution with `var vm = this` convention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34113156/140070

Comment: how to be with other services not $scope that injected in the parent and chilld controllers. For instance, how can we use $routeParams in the parent controller? Is the parent's and child's services independed?

Comment: $controller documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller

Comment: Don't forget to declare the `$controller` in the `ChildCtrl`.

Answer (score 20):

In case you are using [`vm` controller syntax](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), here is my solution:

```
.controller("BaseGenericCtrl", function ($scope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.reload = reload;
    vm.items = [];

    function reload() {
        // this function will come from child controller scope - RESTDataService.getItemsA
        this.getItems();
    }
})

.controller("ChildCtrl", function ($scope, $controller, RESTDataService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getItems = RESTDataService.getItemsA;
    angular.extend(vm, $controller('BaseGenericCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
})
```

Unfortunately, you can't use `$controller.call(vm, 'BaseGenericCtrl'...)`, to pass current context into closure (for `reload()`) function, hence only one solution is to use `this` inside inherited function in order to dynamically change context.

Comment: Couldn't you have just done this instead ?  >  $controller('BaseGenericControl', { vm: vm });

Comment: `vm` is just a variable inside controller, I don't think so Angular could use it as expected.

Answer (score 8):

I think,you should use factory or service,to give accessible functions or data for both controllers.

here is similar question ---> [AngularJS controller inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386137/angularjs-controller-inheritance)

Comment: Yes that is one way, thanks. I came across that post when I was searching for solution. I was thinking if there was some way to load controller function and extend "this" with it.

Comment: I would like to have a universal `loading` variable so that when data is loading I always do the same thing, I don't think factories can do that. My parent controller can have a loading variable but the factory can't manipulate it... right?!

Answer (score 8):

In response to the issue raised in [this answer by gmontague](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30946856/2197555), I have found a method to inherit a controller using $controller(), and still use the controller "as" syntax.

Firstly, use "as" syntax when you inherit calling $controller():

```
    app.controller('ParentCtrl', function(etc...) {
        this.foo = 'bar';
    });
    app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller, etc...) {
        var ctrl = $controller('ParentCtrl as parent', {etc: etc, ...});
        angular.extend(this, ctrl);

    });
```

Then, in HTML template, if the property is defined by parent, then use `parent.` to retrieve properties inherited from parent; if defined by child, then use `child.` to retrieve it.

```
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">{{ parent.foo }}</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, I did this in another way. In my case I wanted a function that apply the same functions and properties in other controllers. I liked it, except by parameters. In this way, all yours ChildCtrls need to receive $location.

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

function BaseCtrl ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.myProp = 'Foo';
    $scope.myMethod = function bar(){ /* do magic */ };
}

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    BaseCtrl.call(this, $scope, $location);

    // it works
    $scope.myMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For those wondering, you can extend component controllers in the same fashion, using the method in the accepted answer.

Use the following approach:

Parent component (to extend from):

```
/**
 * Module definition and dependencies
 */
angular.module('App.Parent', [])

/**
 * Component
 */
.component('parent', {
  templateUrl: 'parent.html',
  controller: 'ParentCtrl',
})

/**
 * Controller
 */
.controller('ParentCtrl', function($parentDep) {

  //Get controller
  const $ctrl = this;

  /**
   * On init
   */
  this.$onInit = function() {

    //Do stuff
    this.something = true;
  };
});
```

Child component (the one extending):

```
/**
 * Module definition and dependencies
 */
angular.module('App.Child', [])

/**
 * Component
 */
.component('child', {
  templateUrl: 'child.html',
  controller: 'ChildCtrl',
})

/**
 * Controller
 */
.controller('ChildCtrl', function($controller) {

  //Get controllers
  const $ctrl = this;
  const $base = $controller('ParentCtrl', {});
  //NOTE: no need to pass $parentDep in here, it is resolved automatically
  //if it's a global service/dependency

  //Extend
  angular.extend($ctrl, $base);

  /**
   * On init
   */
  this.$onInit = function() {

    //Call parent init
    $base.$onInit.call(this);

    //Do other stuff
    this.somethingElse = true;
  };
});
```

The trick is to use named controllers, instead of defining them in the component definition.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can "inherit" a parent controller's modifications to $scope and other services by calling: `$controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope, etc: etc});` in your child controller.

**However**, this fails if you are accustomed to using the controller 'as' syntax, for example in

```
<div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">{{ child.foo }}</div>
```

If `foo` was set in the parent controller (via `this.foo = ...`), the child controller will not have access to it.

As mentioned in comments you can assign the result of $controller directly to the scope:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function(etc...) {
    this.foo = 'bar';
});
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller, etc...) {
    var inst = $controller('ParentCtrl', {etc: etc, ...});

    // Perform extensions to inst
    inst.baz = inst.foo + " extended";

    // Attach to the scope
    $scope.child = inst;
});
```

**Note:** You then **must** remove the 'as' part from `ng-controller=`, because you are specifying the instance name in the code, and no longer the template.

Comment: Using "controller as" syntax has no problem. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36549465/2197555

Answer (score 2):

I was using the "Controller as" syntax with `vm = this` and wanted to inherit a controller. I had issues if my parent controller had a function that modified a variable.

Using [IProblemFactory's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34113156/241211) and [Salman Abbas's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230720/241211) answers, I did the following to have access to parent variables:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp',[])
      .controller('AbstractController', AbstractController)
      .controller('ChildController', ChildController);

  function AbstractController(child) {
    var vm = child;
    vm.foo = 0;
    
    vm.addToFoo = function() {
      vm.foo+=1;
    }
  };
  
  function ChildController($controller) {
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, $controller('AbstractController', {child: vm}));
  };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ChildController as childCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <button type="button" ng-click="childCtrl.addToFoo()">
    add
  </button>
  <span>
      -- {{childCtrl.foo}} --
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JavaScript inheritence mechanism. Also don't forget pass a needly angular services to invoke of .call method.

```
//simple function (js class)
function baseCtrl($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams, $log, $timeout, $window, modalService) {//any serrvices and your 2

   this.id = $routeParams.id;
   $scope.id = this.id;

   this.someFunc = function(){
      $http.get("url?id="+this.id)
      .then(success function(response){
        ....
       } ) 

   }
...
}

angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('childCtrl', childCtrl);

//angular controller function
function childCtrl($http, $scope, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams, $log, $timeout, $window, modalService) {      
   var ctrl = this;
   baseCtrl.call(this, $http, $scope, $location, $rootScope,  $routeParams, $log, $timeout, $window, modalService);

   var idCopy = ctrl.id;
   if($scope.id == ctrl.id){//just for sample
      ctrl.someFunc();
   }
}

//also you can copy prototype of the base controller
childCtrl.prototype = Object.create(baseCtrl.prototype);
```