# AngularJS, DRY controllers for CRUD UI

Tags: angularjs, controller, crud, dry

I have a bunch of data types : users, products, categories. I have a single view/controller for CRUDing each type of data. Therefore, my view allows to create an item, it displays a list, and for each item you can edit and update, or delete it.
The controller manages all UI interactions. For example, when an item is deleted, the user has access to a cancel button for several seconds. Into the controller all CRUD operations are done through services.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(
'UsersManagerController', 
function UsersManagerController($scope, $timeout, userService) {

$scope.deleteUser = function(user) {    
    user.deleting = true;
    user.deletionCancelable = true;
    user.deletePromise = $timeout( function() {
        user.deletionCancelable = false;
        userService.deleteUser(user.id);
    }, 2000);       
};

$scope.isUserDeleting = function(user) {
    return user.deleting;
}

$scope.cancelDelete = function(user) {
    $timeout.cancel(user.deletePromise);
    user.deletePromise = null;
    user.deleting = false;
    user.deletionCancelable = false;
}
```

Now, I would like to avoid repeating this controller code for each type of data (products, categories...), and only write several views. It means I would like a single controller which could receive dynamically a service exposing the CRUD methods for a particular data type. I have managed to do this, using the $injector. **But I don't know how to give the controller the service name from the view.** I have tried this :

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsManagerController" ng-init="setItemService('userService')">
```

And into the controller :

```
    var _crudService;
    $scope.setCrudService = function(serviceName) {
        _crudService = $injector.get(serviceName);
}
```

**But the setCrudService() is called at runtime, managed by the AngularJs binding. It means I cannot known exactly when it will be called, and some other methods of my controller are called before, trying to use the service that has not been set yet.**

Does anyone knows how to do this ?
Maybe my design has a flaw ?

---

**UPDATE :**
I found a solution : scope inheritance.

```
<div ng-controller="UsersManagerController">
<div ng-controller="ItemsManagerController">
    <div ng-repeat="user in items">
        <span ng-click="deleteItem(user.id)">Remove {{user.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

1) UsersManagerController will be initialized first.
2) ItemsManagerController scope will inherit UsersManagerController scope.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('UsersManagerController', 
['$scope', 'userService', function UsersManagerController($scope, userService) {    
    $scope.crudService = userService;
}]);    

angular.module('myApp').controller('ItemsManagerController', 
['$scope', function ItemsManagerController($scope) {    

    $scope.deleteItem = function(itemId) {
        $scope.crudService.delete(itemId);
    }

    $scope.items = crudService.getItems();
}]);
```

It works, but I have to write a controller for each data type. I am still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: The way i've done this before is to create a directive to manage the CRUD operations of an entity, the entity is set in an init function of the directive. Why not have a directive and have 'EntityType' as an attribute and do something similar? The posts back to server can be decided based on the entity. I can elaborate more if this sounds right to you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes, I would like to know more :-) How does the controller will interact with the directive ? If you click the delete button, the controller $scope.deleteItem() is called. How does it know how to delete an item which can be a user, a product or a category ? Also, the views are not the same if the data type is an user or a product. My initial idea is to see the controller as an API provider, and the views use this API.

Comment: You can pass events around into the directive, and hook up callbacks if you wish. I would have a directive for each entity, something like <crud-grid entity="user" /> <crud-grid entity="product" />. In terms of how the data is loaded and saved, I use restangular and each entity has it's own controller, so I can do Restangular.all(entityName).getList()... So the directive itself manages the delete/update/create of the entites. The data looks different for different entities, so I use a meta data controller that returns the fields for an entity, and the crud grid builds itself based on that.

Comment: Another way to do that would be to directly instantiate ItemsManagerController inside UsersManagerController. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-contoller-in-the-same-module

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this way

Setup CRUD generating service

```
app.service('CRUDService', function($timeout) {
  return {

      setCRUD: function(scope, service, objName) {

          var funcName = "delete" + objName;
          scope[funcName] = function(obj) {    
              obj.deleting = true;
              obj.deletionCancelable = true;
              obj.deletePromise = $timeout( function() {
                  obj.deletionCancelable = false;
                  service.deleteUser(user.id);
              }, 2000);       
          };

          funcName = "is" + objName + "Deleting";
          scope[funcName] = function(obj) {
              return obj.deleting;
          }

          scope.cancelDelete = function(obj) {
              $timeout.cancel(obj.deletePromise);
              obj.deletePromise = null;
              obj.deleting = false;
              obj.deletionCancelable = false;
          }    

      }

}
```

Then, in controller, use it

```
   CRUDService.setCRUD($scope, userService, "User");
```

Comment: I like the way you create dynamic functions in the setCRUD object :-) But... It does not fit my needs : how do I give the controller the userService, or the productService ? With your code I have to write a controller for each data type, and the UI interactions code will be repeated in each of them. Right now I have a single controller  which is able to manage all kind of view (the views have to respect the controller API) and all kind of data type through services. How I initialize the controller with the wanted service for a given data type ?