# DRY AngularJS Controllers for forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

I'm using AngularJS on a web project and I am noticing that almost all of my form controllers are looking the same.  The only difference with the login controller (shown below) and say my reset password controller is `$scope.loginForm.$invalid` would be `$scope.resetForm.$invalid` and I would inject and use the `ResetService` instead of the `AuthService`.

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, AuthService) {

  // Form input data
  $scope.formData = {};

  // Are we in the middle of a submit process?
  $scope.busy = false;

  // Has the form been submitted yet?
  $scope.submitted = false;

  // Attempt to submit form via AJAX
  $scope.submit = function (actionUrl) {

    $scope.busy = true;
    $scope.submitted = true;

    // Invalid, activate form and return
    if ($scope.loginForm.$invalid) {
      $scope.busy = false;
      return;
    }

    // Submit data via AJAX
    AuthService.login(actionUrl, $scope.formData).error(function () {
      $scope.busy = false;
    });

  };

});
```

Obviously, this doesn't feel very DRY, and I am assuming that there is an Angular feature or pattern to extract this similar functionality out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FormCtrl` controller was created with all of the functionality.  The 2 items that could vary from form to form are the form name attribute and the AJAX method on the service being used for the form, so I pass those two params in the function after the `$scope`. I then refactored the code a tad to make use of those variables I passed into the function.

The only thing that needs to happen in the `LoginCtrl` (or any other form controller that implements this) is to instantiate the `FormCtrl` and pass it the `$scope`, form name attribute and finally the service method that is used to make the AJAX request.

**login.html**

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl"
      ng-submit="submit('my-ajax-url.php')"
      name="loginForm">
  ...
</form>
```

**FormCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, formName, ajaxFunction) {

  // Form input data
  $scope.formData = {};

  // Are we in the middle of a submit process?
  $scope.busy = false;

  // Has the form been submitted yet?
  $scope.submitted = false;

  // Attempt to submit form via AJAX
  $scope.submit = function (actionUrl) {

    $scope.busy = true;
    $scope.submitted = true;

    // Invalid, activate form and return
    if ($scope[formName].$invalid) {
      $scope.busy = false;
      return;
    }

    // Submit data via AJAX
    ajaxFunction(actionUrl, $scope.formData).error(function () {
      $scope.busy = false;
    });

  };

});
```

**LoginCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $controller, AuthService) {

  // Instantiate form controller
  $controller('FormCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope,
    formName: 'loginForm',
    ajaxFunction: AuthService.login
  });

});
```

Comment: After working with Angular for a while, I've realized that this is NOT the best solution.  Common functionality/properties should be extracted out to a service.  Normally when you create an Angular service, it is a singleton.  However, you might have multiple forms on a page, and therefore you should have your service return a  constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what we have here:

`angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', FUNCTION)`

You can generate these functions from a factory.

In angular, you can add a $inject variable to a function with value being an array of names to injected. Ex:

```
functionName.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
```

When that function is called by angular, $rootScope will be injected. So you can pragmatically inject service to functions.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller(
        'LoginCtrl',
        ControllerFactory.createSubmitController(function(){}, ['$scope', 'AuthService'])
    )
```

Inside of the `createSubmitController`, you create a wrapper function, with all the required names injected. Augment the `$scope` with the functionalities you like, then call the 1st parameter function with all the injected name as well as the augmented `$scope`.

That way you should be able to have the same amount of flexibility, with a good baseline of default behaviors.

You can also invoke injector manually in the factory, so you only need to pass in a function like:

`function($scope, AuthService)`

That's up to you.

See [$inject Annotation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#%24inject%20Annotation)

Comment: What about a controller inheritance pattern similar to this? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20230720/58795

Comment: It is really the same idea. ["It's just a simple call to $injector"](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller) They didn't have that built in when I was looking at angular. I guess that's better if it is built in like that.