# Best practice for Angular JS controller hierarchy/inheritance

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, model-view-controller

Apologies in advance for a very long question, I hope some of you reading this will make it through.

I'm just starting out with angular, and so far I like it, and have been rapidly able to prototype a few of the features we have in our current application, before the "Great rewrite of 2014".  But before we go hell for leather into angular, I want to make sure I'm architecting correctly, and one of the confusions I have is around controller hierarchy and/or inheritance.

Our application is one which is currently divided into logically separate pages, and has a database with a load of different generic entities.  A lot of the pages are structurally *similar* to one another, and typically a page only deals with one type of entity.  For simplicity, let's suppose that it's a cinema booking system ...

So let's say that currently there's a page showing all of the current movies at the cinema, that the data comes from the Movie entity in the database, and that these movies are presented to the user in a table.  The table shows various attributes of the movie (age ratings, length, actors, etc).  When the user clicks on a movie, they are taken to the screenings page, where in a very similar table presents information about the Screening entities (time, available seats, whatever).

At first, I might think to divide my modules/controllers, based upon the logical 'pages' that the user goes to, something like this perhaps:

```
var app = angular.module('MyCinema', ['Movies', 'Screenings']);

var movies = angular.module('Movies', []);
movies.controller('movieCtrl', function() {});
movies.controller('movieTableCtrl', function() {
  // ... do lots of stuff related to the movie table
});


var screenings = angular.module('Screenings', []);
screenings.controller('screeningCtrl', function() {});
screenings.controller('screeningTableCtrl', function() {
  // ... do lots of stuff related to the screening table
});
```

*... In actual fact, I would put these both in their own closures, in separate files, but for brevity, this'll do.*

And in the HTML ...

```
<html ng-app="MyCinema">
  <section ng-controller="movieCtrl">
    <!-- movie related stuff -->
    <table ng-controller="movieTableCtrl"></table>
  </section>
  <section ng-controller="screeningCtrl">
    <!-- screening related stuff -->
    <table ng-controller="screeningTableCtrl"></table>
  </section>
</html>
```

Anyway, I then quickly realise that "do stuff related to the movie table" and "do stuff related to the screening table" are almost identical.  I found this question/answer: [Can an AngularJS controller inherit from another controller in the same module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-contoller-in-the-same-module) and implemented something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyCinema', ['Movies', 'Screenings']);
app.controller('tableCtrl', function() {
  // ... do MOST stuff related to all tables
});

var movies = angular.module('Movies', []);
movies.controller('movieCtrl', function() {});
movies.controller('movieTableCtrl', function($scope) {
  $controller('tableCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
  // ... do a little bit more stuff related to the movie table
});


var screenings = angular.module('Screenings', []);
screenings.controller('screeningCtrl', function() {});
screenings.controller('screeningTableCtrl', function($scope) {
  $controller('tableCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
  // ... do a little bit more stuff related to the screening table
});
```

This works, the controllers kind of have an inheritance thing going on, and the HTML remains the same with the controllers being in the correct sections of the DOM and also in the logically separated modules but ... I don't know, the 'inheritence' doesn't seem clean, it doesn't look like it's something angular wants me to do.  It feels like angular *actually* wants me to do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyCinema', ['Movies', 'Screenings']);
app.controller('tableCtrl', function() {
  // ... do MOST stuff related to all tables
});
app.controller('movieTableCtrl', function($scope) {
  // ... do a little bit more stuff related to the movie table
});
app.controller('screeningTableCtrl', function($scope) {
  // ... do a little bit more stuff related to the screening table
});
```

and in the HTML ...

```
<section ng-controller="movieCtrl">
  <!-- non-table movie stuff -->
</section>
<section ng-controller="screeningCtrl">
  <!-- non-table movie stuff -->
</section>
<div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
  <table ng-controller="movieTableCtrl"></table>
  <table ng-controller="screeningTableCtrl"></table>
</div>
```

So now I don't have to pass $scopes around to get it to work (the scope is implicitly correct in the DOM) and the JS code also looks cleaner, IMO.  However the HTML doesn't express as well how the table stuff is related to the other sections.

So congrats and thanks on getting this far through my question.  My question is now simply, which of these is the preferred style or are they both awful?  Is there a 3rd more best-of-both method that I've missed?

**tldr;** is it considered better to have the controllers in separate modules logical modules, keep the DOM logically separated, and then try and make controllers inherit from one another in the JS ... or it is better to have the DOM specify the inheritance, and sacrifice some logical separation in the JS ... or, something else?

Cheers!!

Comment: That sad moment when your read a good long question and just when yo finish ir you realize it was never answered...

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck on the term "do stuff",  when you say '"do stuff related to the movie table" and "do stuff related to the screening table" are almost identical'. What are you doing?

A controller should just apply your model to your view.

Depending on what you mean, a factory, service or directive might be of better use than a controller for these tables.

Comment: I was trying to be intentionally vague, as the 'stuff' in the example should be basically irrelevant.  And this is only supposed to be a conceptual example anyway in order to try and figure out how one should structure the hierarchy. But, in this example, perhaps the only 'stuff' that isn't common to both the movieTableCtrl and screeningTableCtrl, is API endpoint that the table should communicate with to get the respective models.  Or perhaps a slightly different processing of the data returned by the API is performed before it can be put into the table.