# AngularJS controller inheritance for controllers added to module defintion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

In my angular app i have a module defined in one js file

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```

In another js file I have a base controller defined

```
angular.model('myApp').controller('baseController',
      function($scope){

         $scope.var1 = 'foo';
         $scope.func1 = function(){
           // do something
         }
      }
   )
```

now based on [Can an AngularJS controller inherit from another controller in the same module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-contoller-in-the-same-module) I want to create a controller in another js file that inherits from baseController and adds some fields and functions eg

```
angular.model('myApp').controller('myController',
      $injector.invoke(baseController, this, {$scope: $scope}); 
      }
   )
```

But this gives an error as it does not know about baseController. I have tried putting baseController in '' but no help.

Any ideas.
Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like that, you'll need to write a service that will share data between your controllers.

you can checkout this link for more info about [services](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/)
and then, inject the service in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs is using prototypical inheritance where child controllers inherit $scope from parent controllers. The only thing you need to do is to wrap a child controller with a parent:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="parentAction()">parent action 1</button>
    <button ng-click="parentAction2()">parent action 2</button>
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
       <button ng-click="parentAction()">parent action 1</button>
       <button ng-click="parentAction2()">parent action 2</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parentAction = function () {
    alert('hello from parrent');
  };
  $scope.parentAction2 = function () {
    alert('hello from parrent 2');
  };
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.childAction = function () {
    alert('hello from child');
  };

  $scope.parentAction2 = function () {
    alert('overridden action');
  };

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6VYCJIemg0cQCYG8jVDF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative if you don't want to create a hierarchy with yours controllers.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="parentAction()">parent action 1</button>
    <button ng-click="parentAction2()">parent action 2</button>
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
       <button ng-click="parentAction()">parent action 1</button>
       <button ng-click="parentAction2()">parent action 2</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

So if this hierarchy doesn't fit your needs, you could create inheritance as the old school by prototyping yours controllers..

Here code example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/ry90eoqt/2/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var parent = function($scope){
        $scope.parent = function(){
            alert('parent method');
        }
    };

    // you could do some prototyping as well
//parent.prototype.parent2 = function(){
//    alert('parent2 method');
//};

    var child = function($scope){
        parent.call(this, $scope);
        //$scope.parent2 = this.parent2;
    };
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;


app.controller('parent', parent);

app.controller('myController', child);
```