# Inheriting angular controller objects

Tags: angularjs, inheritance

I don't really understand how to inherit controller objects in angular (not using $scope), when we're surrounding them in a IIFE.

So assume we have 2 controller files:

Animal.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('animalCtrl', function() {
        this.strength = 3;
        this.speed = 3;
});
})();
```

Beaver.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('beaverCtrl', function() {
        //How do I inherit the parent controllers stats?
});
})();
```

How can I inherit from animalCtrl using my beaverCtrl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an AngularJS controller inherit from another contoller in the same module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-contoller-in-the-same-module)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to share data on any angularjs site is by using services. In this case I would create a factory that will store strength and speed and share it with beaverCtrl.

```
angular.module('<yourappname>', [])
  .factory('dataService', function() {
    $scope = this;

    $scope.strength = null;
    $scope.speed = null;

    $scope.setStrength = function(value) {
      $scope.strength = value;
    }

    $scope.setSpeed = function(value) {
      $scope.speed = value;
    }
    return $scope;
})
```

Then in the controllers you would call the service like this

```
.controller('animalCtrl', function(dataService) {
  this.strength = 3;
  this.speed = 3;

  dataService.setStrength(this.strength);
  dataService.setSpeed(this.speed);

});

.controller('beaverCtrl', function(dataService) {
  this.strength = dataService.strength;
  this.speed = dataService.speed;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize that an AngularJS controller is just a normal javascript "class". The only catch is invoking the base constructor with dependency injection.

```
// Create some base class.
BaseController = function($scope, $route) {
  // Do some stuff here.
};

// The base class has some behavior.
BaseController.prototype.someMethod = function() { /* do something */ };

// Create some child class.
ChildController = function($scope, $injector) {
  // Invoke the base constructor.
  $injector.invoke(this, BaseController, {$scope: $scope});
};

// Inherit from the base class.
ChildController.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);

// Add more specific behavior.
ChildController.prototype.someChildMethod = function() { /* do something */ };
```

Then you can register your controller as

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ChildController', ChildController);
```

Keep in mind that using inheritance like this will be problematic if overused. It should only be used for sharing *behavior*. Additionally, using composition of different "classes" is generally going to be much more flexible than using inheritance.

From a code organization standpoint, I would also recommend that you declare your controllers in one place (one file per controller) and register them onto modules in another place (one file per module).

Comment: I'm a bit confused how you can call $injector.invoke(this, BaseController, {$scope: $scope}); If the controllers are in different files with an IIFE surrounding them, then the BaseController isn't visible to the ChildController. I guess this is more of a javascript issue than an angular one, but your response was helpful.

Comment: I omitted the organization parts to keep the example simple. In a real application, you'd want to have some kind of _load-time_ module system. Angular modules deal with _run-time_ dependencies (i.e., configuring the dependency injector and html compiler).