# AngularJS service $routeChangeStart

Tags: angularjs

I got the following working great in each controller.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
    $scope.closeitup();
});
```

And in every controller i got a `closeitup()` function that does something different but with the same name.

How can i move the above `$scope.$on` to a service that will be fired and call the controller `closeitup()`

Hope the question is clear enough

Comment: Can you also post `closeitup()` functions so that we could see the difference between them?

Comment: It is different code in every controller but as an example: $scope.closeitup = function (){  some $http call  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myModule.factory('closeitupOnRouteChangeStart', function() {
  return function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
      $scope.closeitup();
    });
  };
});
```

and in the controller:

```
myModule.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, closeitupOnRouteChangeStart) {
  closeitupOnRouteChangeStart($scope);
});
```

I'm not sure this makes the code cleaner and more readable, though.

Comment: It is not working, it says `TypeError closeitupOnRouteChangeStart is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

What about using $controller inheritance?

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event){
    $scope.closeitup();
  });
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
});
```

- Example adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module#answer-20230720) by [SalmanPK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362006/salmanpk)

Didn't tried that myself, so sorry if the approach is misleading.

Comment: I did not try this but i want to move the code to a service. thanks though i will look into `$controller` as i did not know about it

Comment: If you just need to encapsulate that logic somewhere, the controller inheritance sounds good.

If not, try "JB Nizet" answer, and please give him accepted state if it solves your problem. :D