# Inherit $scope and vm(this) angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a base controller and controllers that I would like to inherit the base controllers variable and functions. But I'm have trouble inhering **'vm'** varand the functions.

How do I pass the **vm** for the other controllers to

BaseController.js

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Base', function($scope){
     var vm = this;

     $scope.test1 = "this is a test";
     vm.test2 = 'this is a second test";     
   });
```

FirstController.js

```
angular
  .modlue('app')
  .controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $controller){
    $controller('Base', { $scope: $scope });
    console.log($scope);
  });
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module

Comment: @ste2425 I'll try this.