# how can I change a value of a variable from nested controller and viceversa

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, controllers

I need to change the mensaje variable from the "padre controller" and visualize it.
and change the variable from the "hijo controller" and viceversa, but it's not working

if a click in "cambiar padre" the value change, if a click in "cambiar desde el hijo", it's working, but when I click again in "cambiar desde el padre" it's not working anymore

js

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

  .controller('padre', function ($scope) {

    $scope.mensaje = "hola";

    $scope.cambiarPadre = function () {
      $scope.mensaje = "texto modificado desde el padre";
    };


  })

  .controller("hijo", function ($scope) {


    $scope.cambiarHijo = function () {
      console.log('entro a cambiar hijo : ');

      $scope.mensaje = "texto modificado desde el hijo";
    };

    $scope.cambiarPadreDesdeHijo = function () {
      console.log('entro a cambiar hijo : ');

      $scope.$parent.mensaje = "texto modificado desde el hijo";
    };

  })
```

html

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard" ng-controller="padre as p">
  <ion-content class="padding">

    DEL PADRE
    <br>

    padre:{{mensaje}}
    <br>
    hijo:{{mensaje}}

    <br>
    <br>


    <button ng-click="cambiarPadre()">cambiar desde el padre</button>


    <div ng-controller="hijo as h">

      DEL HIJO sin nada
      <br>
      sin parent:
      <br>
      padre:{{mensaje}}
      <br>
      hijo:{{mensaje}}

      <br>
      <br>

      con parent:
      <br>
      padre:{{$parent.mensaje}}
      <br>
      hijo:{{$parent.mensaje}}
      <br>

      <button ng-click="cambiarHijo()">cambiar desde el hijo</button>
      <br>

      <br>
      <button ng-click="cambiarPadreDesdeHijo()">cambiar padre desde hijo</button>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: make them components and pass down props with `=`, stop using `ng-controller`

Answer (score 1):

It's not the proper way to access a value from another controller. If you really want to share data between them you should use a service to store the value and both controllers can change that value. If you really want to do inheritance between the controllers you should try something  from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module).
Beside this I'm not sure if the parent of "hijo" will be the "padre" because you use it form ion-* directives. The possible problem why it does not work comes from the nature of javascript ([prototipical inheritance](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance)) and you probably does not write the same variable that the controller reads.