# $routeParams not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the $routeParams service.
when i `console_log($routeParams)` the service in my controller i see in the console all the values.

However when i console log $routeParams.id i get undefined.
( when i console out $routeParams i see the parameters )

i am able to get the values only if i use timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
}, 100);
```

any idea why that happens? its really weird and i think i am missing something.

Comment: can you post sample fiddler for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519937/routeparams-is-empty-in-main-controller, the top answer provides a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative way:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    // $routeParams.id exists
});
```

Comment: You're the man!, this was properly doing my nuts in I might consider stateProvider tho